# Laravel groupBy and pluck some values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am using laravel 8.x and building rest API project.
I am stuck with a query.

I have a table

| id | name | type | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dog | animal | black |
| 2 | Dog | animal | yellow |
| 3 | Cat | animal | red |
| 4 | Cat | animal | white |

I want to do something like that,

`$animals->groupBy('name')->get()`

and hope to get result like,

```
$animals=[
          {
           name: "dog",
           type: "animal",
           colors: ["black", "yellow"]
          },
          {
           name: "cat",
           type: "animal",
           colors: ["red", "white"]
          }
         ]
```

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will slightly improve the Erik answer.

```php
        $animals = Animals::all()->groupBy('name')->map(function($item) {
            return [
                'name' => $item[0]['name'], // the name always the same
                'type' => $item[0]['type'], // if the type not change (as the name)
                'colors' => $item->pluck('color')->unique()->toArray(),
            ];
        })->values()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Laravel mapToGroups collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-maptogroups)

```
$data = Animal::get();

$animals = collect($data)->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
            return [$item['name'] => $item];
        })->map(function ($itemGoup, $name) {
            return [
                'name' => $name,
                'type' => data_get($itemGoup, '0.type'),
                'colors' => collect($itemGoup)->pluck('color')->unique()->values()->toArray(),
            ];
        })->values()->toArray();
```

with output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Dog",
        "type": "animal",
        "colors": ["black", "yellow"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Cat",
        "type": "animal",
        "colors": ["red", "white"]
    }
]
```